# my dataframe giving wrong dimensions in r

Tags: r, list, matrix

```
  complete <-function(directory,id){

  #path<-directory
     mymatrix <- matrix()
      rowc<-1
 # mylist <- list()

      for(i in id){
    fileStr <- paste(directory, "/", sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(i)), ".csv", 
                     sep = "")

    #filename<-paste(i,".csv",sep="")
    #mydata<- read.csv((file=file.path(path, filename)), header=TRUE)
        mydata<-read.csv(fileStr)
   #cleandframe<- mydata[complete.cases(mydata),]
    numCOmpleteCases<- sum(complete.cases(mydata))

   #mymatrix(i,numCOmpleteCases)

   # mylist[[rowc]]<- cbind(c(i,numCOmpleteCases))

  mymatrix[rowc,] <-c(i,numCOmpleteCases)
    rowc<- rowc+1
    dframeComplete<-data.frame(id=i,nobs=numCOmpleteCases)


  }
  #dframeComplete<- (data.frame(id=id, nobs=sapply(id,numCompleteCases)))
  #dframeComplete
   mymatrix<-as.data.frame(mymatrix)
   mymatrix

  }
```

I am trying to pruduce a dataframe with two columns, id and numCompleteCases, I have tried with both a list and a matrix, with a list I am getting a dataframe with columns equivalent to the number of pairs of (id,numCompleteCases) instead of a dataframe with 2 columns and a number of rows eqivalent to the pairs passed.

Comment: is it `id` a numeric vector? `i` don't run over the loop

Comment: yes it is a numeric vector, both i and numCompleteCases are numeric, I'm noticing that using c() function makes all of its argument entries in one column, is there a way of making these entries of one row?

Comment: for the row problem with the list just change `mylist[[rowc]]<- cbind(c(i,numCOmpleteCases))`to `mylist[[rowc]]<- cbind(t(c(i,numCOmpleteCases)))` i.e. transpose the vector

Comment: for your other problem: change `mymatrix <- matrix()` to `mymatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(id), ncol = 2)`

Comment: thank you , the matrix version worked , though the list one didnt , but problem solved